# Razor Pay checkout form not appearing and giving error as not a function

Tags: javascript, angular7

I am implementing `razorPay` payment in `angular7` project.I am trying to open checkout form by creating a single instance of Razorpay and accessing its function `open()`. But instead it is throwing error "is not a function". I couldn't find any proper documentation regarding this.

However, If I try to simple create payment using razorpay, it opens up the window but there is no option for user to choose any method and hence it throws error again because directly creating payment will not add up any card(if method is 'card'). So it is necessary to open checkout form.

Here is my function I am using, firstly i create order on server to generate id and then proceed to payment.

```js
   buyPlan() {
       let postdata = {
         amount: 1000,
         currency: "INR",
         receipt: "1",
         notes: {},
         payment_capture: true
       }
       this.common.createOrder(postdata).subscribe(
         (result: any) => {
           console.log(result)
           var razorpay = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay({
             key: 'dashboard_key_id',
             image: 'assets/images/logo-1.png',
           });
           var data = {
             amount: 1000,
             currency: "INR",
             email: 'abc@example.com',
             contact: '9874563210',
             notes: {
               address: 'Sector 65 Delhi',
             },
             method: 'card',
             order_id: result.data.id,
             handler: function (response) {
               alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
             }
           };
           razorpay.open();
         }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         }
       );
     }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes the script which we add in index.html needed to be changed. After changing it to checkout.js from razorpay.js, it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

For Custom Integration

Remove:

```
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
```

from index.html file
and put:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>
```

inside `<head></head>` tag